# How to resolve the error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in Kakao Talk Login sample application?

Tags: android

I've followed the sample application for kakao talk login from developers.kakao console, if I run the sample application, it's working fine, but if I do the same creating new project I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.kakao.authorization.accesstoken.GetterAccessToken.makeAccessTokenRequest(GetterAccessToken.java:116)
at com.kakao.authorization.accesstoken.GetterAccessToken.requestAccessToken(GetterAccessToken.java:56)
at com.kakao.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:78)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the error type and how to start resolve it?

Comment: it is coming because of facebook sdk just remove android support libary from build path of facebook sdk

Comment: And also remove asyn task http client libary from kakao sdk

Comment: I am also using facebook sdk with this one. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using facebook sdk and kakao sdk together, there is a session problem in it.
For this just remove Asyn HTTP client libary from build path of you kakao sdk ans it will run fine after that